# Difference between Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu server with ubuntu-desktop package

Tags: server, desktop-environments, 22.04, pxe

I'm using PXE to install Ubuntu 22.04 (and other versions) based on information from https://www.molnar-peter.hu/en/ubuntu-jammy-netinstall-pxe.html and other sources. Basically all information (and my own tests) shows that autoinstall need to use the server distribution instead of the desktop distribution as the desktop dist does not use Subiquity so that autoinstall can be achieved.

As I'm installing Ubuntu for use as an desktop OS for the laptops in the organization, I want the installation to be as close to a stock installed Ubuntu Desktop as possible.

So my question is: How much difference is there between a stock installation of Ubuntu Desktop and an installation of Ubuntu server and then adding the ubuntu-desktop package on top of that?

Thx / David

Comment: The big differences that I have seen is that Ubuntu Server includes `openssh-server`, which is unnecessary attack surface on many desktops, and that Ubuntu Server uses networkd while Ubuntu Desktop uses NetworkManager -- so double-check that netplan is set up for NM.

Comment: Thx @user535733. Actually ssh is needed for other reasons so that might be a good thing for us but the aspect of of NM versus systemd is a good point!